# Entity Framework 6.0 Data reader with threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-6, datareader

I have use repository pattern with Entity Framework 6.0. Below is the code which we are using to retrieve multiple result sets of data from the database, for this we have used a data reader.

```
public InquiryResponse GetInquiry(long ID)
{
        // Create container ready for the resultsets
        var result = new InquiryResponse();

        // Create command from the context in order to execute
        var command = tDataContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetInquiryByID] @Id";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", ID));

        try
        {
            // Open connections
            if (tDataContext.Database.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                // Open connections
                tDataContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            }

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // the `Translate` method
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)tDataContext).ObjectContext;

            // Read Entity1 from the first resultset
            result = objectContext.Translate<InquiryResponse>(reader).FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                // Read Entity2 from the second resultset
                reader.NextResult();
                result.InquiryDetail = objectContext.Translate<InquiryDetail >(reader).ToList();
            }

            if (result != null && result.ID <= 0)
            {
                result = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close connections
            tDataContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

We are calling this function in multiple threads, some time we receives different error in production environment, see error details from below.

> Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed
>
> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
>
> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.

I did found proper solution to resolve above issues, I appreciate your help to get proper solution.

Let me know if anything is missing, so I will add the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In short you this is a very flakey design and is bound to fail.

- Never share a `Context` or `Connection` like this
- Never try to cache a `Context` or `Connection`
- Always open a `Context` or `Connection` with a `using` statement
- Try to wok as atomically as you can with `Context` or `Connection`
- If you really feel the need to share a Context in a threaded environment, make sure you are appropriately locking, EF is not thread safe (at all).

Moreover, if you let *EF* take care of the connections and pooling and use a `using` statement you will find things will just work. Only after *EF* is not throwing exceptions then we can discuss architectures for performance

**Additional resources**

[Entity Framework Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737)

[Entity Framework Connection Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849)